# Type '`/${string}/menu/${number}`' is not assignable to type 'StaticRoutes | RelativePathString | `${string}:${string}`'

Tags: react-native, expo-router

```
import { defaultImage } from "@/constants"
import Colors from "@/constants/Colors"
import { Product } from "@/types"
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { Link, useRouter, useSegments } from "expo-router"
import { Image, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native"

type ProductListIt`emProps={
    product:Product
}
const ProductListItem = ({product}:ProductListItemProps) => {
  const segment=useSegments();
  const seg=segment[0] || "";

  return (
    **<Link href={`/${seg}/menu/${product.id}`} asChild>**
    <Pressable  style={styles.container} >
    <Image style={{width:'100%',aspectRatio:1}} source={{uri:product.image || defaultImage}} resizeMode="contain"/>
    <Text style={s`tyles.title}>{product.name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.price}>{product.price}</Text>
  </Pressable>
  </Link>
  )
}

export default ProductListItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor:'white',
      padding:10,
      borderRadius:20,
      flex:1,
      maxWidth:'50%'
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    price: {
      marginVertical: 5,
      color:Colors.light.tint
    },
  });
```

In JSX the Link statement giving me this error Type '`/${string}/menu/${number}`' is not assignable to type 'StaticRoutes | RelativePathString | `${string}:${string}`'.

I am using expo router

can anyone help me that why my Link is not taking the segment[0] as route